# Adobe Premiere Elements 11 Crash Issues (Adobe Premiere Elements has stopped working)

Tags: software, video-editor

After installing Adobe Premiere Elements 11 Trial I opened the Editor and pressed **New Project**. Than our beloved Windows error: **Adobe Premiere Elements has stopped working** contact there, do this, do that error... It just crashed...

Restarted the computer... No

There were some video related services running I stopped them... No

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I'm just answering this question in case someone has the same issue...

**Short Story:**

1. **Update your graphics card drivers. (All of them!)**
2. **If you have more than 1 card be sure the stronger one handles adobe premiere.**

**Long Story:**

My laptop has 2 graphic cards

1. Intel HD Graphics
2. NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M

First I updated the driver of Intel HD graphics by uninstalling it from Device Manager (which is a bad idea as the screen disappears any way) then restarted my computer. Than Windows found the driver, installed it Restart number 2.

Now I tried Elements, great it worked! But... consuming 7.5 GB of RAM!!! (Virtual and Physical combined)

This time I don't know why, I just had to try it, I updated my NVIDIA driver (which had 2 updates) and from NVIDIA console I marked Adobe Premiere Elements.exe to use the NVIDIA graphics card.

Than I tried it and Elements worked perfectly...